# Adding a subrepo in a subfolder in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-subrepos

I want to have a sub-repository in a sub-folder.

Here is the line from my hgsub file:

`Common\Vectors = http://my.rhodecode.org/DotNETSources/DotNETCommon/Vectors`

At first it seemed to work, as TortoiseHG showed the subrepos and didn't blow up right away. However, I don't seem to be able to commit changes to the parent repo. The commit goes without hickup but the sub-repos are still marked as changed and .hgsubstate file does not change.

Is this even possible? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Try to use *Nix path-delimiter in LH: `Common/Vectors`

Answer (score 0):

The parent is modified if you commit in the parent repository. And it will commit the children repositories as well (with -S option, or by setting the right options in TortoiseHG). But committing in the children doesn't commit the parent.